# changing ShinyDash default back ground color and force grids on same row

Tags: r, shiny

I am using a R package 'ShinyDash' in my shiny app. By default the background color of the screen is gray. Firstly, Is there any option that we can change this to white? Secondly, can I force the gridsterItems to be on same row. My chartOutputs are not in same row, even if I use below code.

```
gridster(tile.width = 250, tile.height = 250,
                          gridsterItem(row = 1, col = 1, size.x = 1, size.y = 1,                   
                                                chartOutput("firstChart")),
                          gridsterItem(row = 1, col = 2, size.x = 1, size.y = 1,
                                       chartOutput("secondChart"))
                          )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this to change background color `style='background-color:#FFFFFF'` after `size.y=1`. I am still unable to force them to be on same row.

Comment: Can you share your code as a gist on Github so we can take a look?